# NSUserDefaults will not work after running this script

Tags: ios

I was trying to reset NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults with the following script and now whatever I do I can't get NSUserDefaults to work on my iPhone.

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

The script was run whilst testing app with my iPhone. Nevertheless, NSUserDefaults is working whilst running with the simulator. This is because I deleted the script before running with simulator.

Comment: That is not a script, that is objective-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop running in Xcode. Then delete the app from the iPhone. All fixed!

Comment: well, thats what I thought would work but it doesn't. I actually restarted laptop, deleted app and restarted iPhone. Any other ideas ??

Comment: In your original question, could you say more exactly what "doesn't work"?

Comment: after adding the code NSUserDefaults no longer retrives old or new data when using with iphone.I know its not a problem with my code because it was working well before I added this script plus NSUserDefaults works fine using the simulator with the same app.

Comment: I've tried [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults]; but that hasn't worked. If i were to add another device i'm sure it would all work fine.The reason it wont work on the iPhone is because that is what I was using when I run the app with the code - does that make sense ??

Comment: No, it doesn't! When you delete the app, you delete its sandbox; there are no defaults any more. I really would like to see an example of what you think isn't working. Just try putting a value into the defaults and retrieving it (in the next line). I bet it works fine.

Comment: No still not working - but I think the problem might be to do with the over usage of NSUserDefaults. Lots of arrays and dictionaries being saved.So, Im going to stop using defaults and start using plists. Thanks for your time.